# Функция которая находится в другом файле

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Как сделать функцию вне основного блока с ботом, т.е. в экспортирующем файле test.py который импортирую в основной файл где находится бот?
Вот так не выходит (даже если подключен telebot и токен):

```
def foo(arg):
    bot.reply_to(message, arg)
```

Пробовал также message заменить на другой аргумент и где нужно передавать уже этот самый message - также ломается.

Comment: так передавай в foo оба аргумента, откуда вообще должна функция брать переменную message? Из файла с функцией или из основного файла, в который импортируется?

Answer (score 0):

А что именно вы экспортируете из test.py?

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно вложить импортируемую функцию в ту, что декорируется обработчиком сообщений:

```python
    from test import another_func 

    @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"]) 
    def default_func(message):
        another_func(message)
```

Comment: Экспортирую функцию, но проблема в том что там нет библиотеки бота, даже если я подключу, эта функция не работает когда из test.py переношу в файл с ботом. Экспортирую я также как и вы, только свои значения.
Как я понял, такое сделать невозможно.